# imagegif() function not working properly

Tags: php, image, heroku, gd

Hello everyone I am trying to write a string on image during runtime and for this purpose I am using `imagestring` from GD, but am not getting the required output instead its giving met his error:

`imagegif(): Unable to open 'temp/textImage.gif' for writing: No such file or directory in … on line 157 Warning:`

However this same code was working fine with `imagefttext()` function, but as my hosting provider `heroku` does not support freetype library so that’s why ive to switch.

```
        $message = “Hello World”;
        //Image Processing:
        $imageUrl = "image.gif";
        $imageId = imagecreatefromgif($imageUrl);

        $angle = 0;
        $xCord = 4;
        $yCord = 40;
        $imageColor = imagecolorallocate($imageId, 0, 0, 0);
        $fontUrl = "GOTHIC.TTF";
        $imageText = "HELOOOO";
        $imageTextLnght = strlen($imageText);
        $fontSize = (500 / $imageTextLnght) + 5;
        $imageFont = 1;

//imagefttext($imageId, $fontSize, $angle, $xCord, $yCord, $imageColor, $fontUrl, $imageText);
        imagestring($imageId, 5, $xCord, $yCord, $imageText, $imageColor);
        //header('Content-Type: image/gif');

        //Saving Image With Text:
        $textImage = 'temp/textImage.gif';
        imagegif($imageId, $textImage);
        imagedestroy($imageId);
```

Kindly help me with this:
Thankyou

Comment: there is, as i said the very same code is working pretty fine with `imagefttext` and `'temp/textImage.gif'` is not an existing file but rather the filename to save the text added file.

Comment: Check the folder `temp` and path. If not create `temp` folder with the same directory php script manually, and give 777 permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `temp` exists, or create it with `mkdir`.

Usually the error `Unable to open .. No such file or directory` when trying to create a file means that the directory doesn't exist.